# Return jpeg from cURL

Tags: php, curl

Trying to display a jpeg image via cURL.
I have tried various attribute options using `curl_setopt` and searching through various threads but haven't figured this out. Upon displaying the return shows up as below:

[Output Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIEkd.jpg)

This is the current code

```
$url = 'http://172.18.0.1:9000/admin_Background.jpg';

$ch = curl_init();

$headers    = [];
$headers[]  = 'Content-Type: image/jpeg';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$resultcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: this looks more like PHP code than a curl invocation ;p

Comment: ```$ch=curl_init($url);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,function($ch,$header){header($header);});curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);```

Comment: Are you outputting this as part of a larger HTML file? It's extremely hard to see anything useful in that "Output" image, but it looks like you may be echoing raw binary data into an HTML page. Well, that's not how images work. You need an `<img>` tag which refers to a `src` URL which returns that image.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting the contents of a JPG file (though it's hard to tell with the output image you supplied). In order to display this in the browser you have two choices:

Save the contents to a file and output an image tag: `<img src="local_file.jpg">`

Or:

Encode the JPG contents as base64 and display it inline in the image tag:

```
$base64_image = base64_encode($result);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' . $base64_image . '"/>';
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used the encode option noted and the output display now shows a small box with a question mark - certainly different than without using the $base64_image and the accompanying echo command. But is there something else I need to do ?  Just a note the original curl snip-it is within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the only output is the JPG image, a third option is to add

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

before the echo statement.

This will tell the browser to render the output as an image instead of text. Usually there would be a separate HTML/PHP page with an image tag with src="yourPHPscript.php".